# Forcing orientation change in android on button click stops further config change detection

Tags: android, android-activity, android-orientation

In one of my activities, I am forcing the screen orientation to landscape on a button click by setting

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

It works fine.

Now I want the application to follow the sensor so that orientation is brought back to portrait when tilted back to portrait.

If the orientation is forced to landscape, orientation will remain in landscape even if you tilt back to portrait mode. Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Is there a way we can set "setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);" for the android system to start detecting the config changes again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, So I found a solution to this problem as to reset the orientation to SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR after a few seconds so the sensor will start to work again..

inside onClik(),

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);

        }
    }, 2000);
```